¿Cuál es la mejor opcion de lenguaje y BD para hacer una descarga masiva de XML?
Estoy asignado a hacer de apoyo para poder hacer un sistema de descarga masiva de xml que momentáneamente será de manera local pero se pretende hacer en linea,
¿Cuál seria el mejor lenguaje para utilizar, unos me dicen Python, otros C#, Otros Java?
¿Qué me recomiendan?

Te recomiendo usar lo que conozcas.
